# Write multiple line on netbeans?

Tags: java, user-interface, file-handling

how can I write multiple lines so that I am able to record all achievements without overwriting the content? Thank you.

```
    private void view_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    
    
    try{         
    FileWriter FW = new FileWriter(""+StudRecord+"/"+LRN_Field.getText()+".txt");
    System.out.print(achievement_Field.getText());
    FW.write(""+achievement_Field.getText()+"");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Achievement Added");
    achievement_Field.setText(" ");
    FW.close();
    
    }catch(Exception e){  
     System.out.print((e));
    }
}
```

[THE GUI IM WORKING ON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIxmG.png)

Comment: API docs are [your friend](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileWriter.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.File,boolean))

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the file for writing, and your text will be the content of the file. Instead, open the file for appending.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileWriter.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.File,boolean)